# Wireframe plot with small values in R

Tags: r, lattice

I have data with very small values between -1 to 1 in X, Y and Z values between -1 to 1 like below

```
X,Y,Z
-0.858301,-1,1.00916
-0.929151,-1,1.0047
-0.896405,-0.940299,1.00396
-0.960967,-0.944075,1.00035

wireframe(Z~X+Y,data=sol)
```

Seems wireframe works only with larger values (1, 2, 3...) , How do I plot small values?

Comment: `wireframe` being a function from what package?

Comment: You need to include calls to all non-base packages in your example, i.e., `library("lattice")`.

Comment: It's not an issue with small values. `lattice::wireframe` requires z values spaced on an X-Y grid. (Otherwise it doesn't "know" how to draw it's pseudo-3d polygons.) Since you have a different plotting situation, you either need to interpolate or use a different tool. There is an interp function in pkg:akima. Do some searching on SO and rhalp archives for worked examples.

Comment: I do have x, y location for z values as above. for example, I can multiply with 1000 so I need to put z = 1.0 at x = 858 and y = 1000 but it gives me blank chart

Comment: Your X and Y variables do not appear to be on a grid. I repeat, the  y values are NOT the issue.

Comment: My X, Y values can be put on grid of high resolution by multiplying by 1000 and rounding. My problem was that they were not plotting by "wireframe" command.  Calling "expand.grid" does exactly what I need, expand the grid (accepted answer below).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`wireframe` might be use in one of two ways -

With a rectangular data matrix where the values of `x` and `y` are implied by the shape of the matrix.

```
wireframe(matrix(rnorm(100),ncol=5),drape=TRUE)
```

Or with a dataframe, where the values of `x` and `y` are explicit, and here you can use a formula for the relationships between the columns.

```
df<-expand.grid(x = seq(0,.1,.01), y = seq(0,.1,.01))
df$z<-rnorm(121)
wireframe(z~x*y,data=df,drape=TRUE)
```

Comment: I have z values in my matrix but as you can see, my x and y values are extremely small.  If I round these values, I am getting the plot but it is not accurate obviously because I loose precision.

Comment: My grid is not symmetrical which is why I need precise values, e.g. x = 1.1, y = -1.05, z = 2.3

Comment: It seems it doesn't allow x and y double values, what are other options?

Comment: As BondedDust pointed out, this really isn't an issue of precision or small values, I can use small values in `z` and still get a good looking plot, `wireframe(matrix(rnorm(100,0,.000001),ncol=5),drape=TRUE)`. It is now unclear what your difficulty is. Can you provide an image of the erroneous plot?

Comment: above is the link.. I just multiplied my x, y by 10 and rounded so it became 1, 2 .. instead of 0.881 etc.. but the surface is not sharp enough. I need to multiply, round values by 10000 since its taking only integers.  My problem is very simple.. i just need higher resolution of x and y points!!

Comment: basically, I just need larger grid so I can have more precise x, y coordinates.

Comment: You say 'its taking only integers', but that's not the case. See my edited example above - we can use `expand.grid` to make a grid of whatever size and precision we need.

Comment: Yes, it does.. sorry, my bad!

Answer (score 0):

I've found that if you include the line defining the z axis limits, then you can't draw it below 1.  But if you take out the defined axis limits, and let R graph it itself, then it works and you can graph small numbers.